# XSLT where to begin from?

Tags: xslt

I am on a mission to study XSLT. I would like to let you know that I haven't any experience with XML. What I need is to grasp in a nutshell what XSLT is, and what is it used for. I hope you can guide me in finding books or articles (free if possible) to make me aware of its basic features.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Start by googling it. Come back when you will have **specific** question concerning some problems you've faced. Searching for books and tutorials is [offtopic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at StackOverflow.

Comment: Have a look at [XSLT Quickly](https://www.manning.com/books/xslt-quickly) and [Google for XSLT Foundations](https://www.google.nl/search?q=xslt+foundations). And there is some condensed info with pointers, links etc on the [xslt tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good resource for learning XSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271/what-is-a-good-resource-for-learning-xsl)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759096(v=vs.85).aspx (What Is XSLT? - Microsoft)
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xmldo/ (Five XML dos and five don'ts that you need to know - IBM)
http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/ (Jeni's XSLT Pages, containing various Tutorials)
http://www2.sims.berkeley.edu/academics/courses/is290-8/s04/lectures/5/dragons/allslides.html (There are Monsters in My Closet or How Not to Use XSLT)